# hardware back button is called twice ionic5

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic5

I try to configure hardware back button and call a function inside it:

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
  this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
    //call my function here
  });
}
```

but when i click on the button it's called twice.I'm working with ionic5.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try async and await as follow

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
    constructor(private platform: Platform) {
      this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, async () => {
        await this.functionCall() // Your function call goes here
      });
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help but button still executed twice.